# Typescript - key/property type guard

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Can I create a typeguard which asserts that a particular property exists (or has a specific type) in an object.

I.e

I have an interface `Foo`:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
    buzz?: string;
}
```

Now an object of type `Foo` will have an optional property buzz. How would I write a function which asserts that buzz exists:
i.e

```
const item: Foo = getFooFromSomewhere();

if (!hasBuzz(item)) return;

const str: string = item.buzz;
```

How would I implement `hasBuzz()`?. Something along the lines of a typeguard:

```
function hasBuzz(item: Foo): item.buzz is string {
    return typeof item.buzz === 'string'
}
```

Does something like this exist?

PS: I understand I can just do:

```
const item = getFooFromSomewhere();

if (typeof item.buzz === 'string') return;

const str: string = item.buzz;
```

But my actual use-case requires me to have a separate function which asserts the existence of `buzz`.

Comment: Use `"buzz" in item`?

Answer (score 14):

I don't like the existing answers here because they are all specific to checking a `Foo` object, but you can define a `hasBuzz` typeguard that will check *any* object to see if it has a `buzz` property.

```
interface Buzzable {
    buzz: string;
}

function hasBuzz<T extends {buzz?: any}>(obj: T): obj is T & Buzzable {
    return typeof obj.buzz === "string";
}
```

By using a generic `T` for the input and returning `obj is T & Buzzable` rather than just `obj is Buzzable` you won't lose any information about specific interfaces such as `Foo` when checking with `hasBuzz`.

If `hasBuzz(item: Foo)` is `true`, then typescript knows that the type of `item` is `Foo & Buzzable`.  In this case that is the same as `Required<Foo>` since `Foo` has an optional `buzz` property, but you can check any object.  `hasBuzz({})` is perfectly valid, and should always return `false`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcBem4CMA2KA3gFDLnK5aYBcyAzmFKAOYDcJAviSTOiAjDAA9iGQALOPQzYAPABVkEAB6QQAE3rIiVbAH46cEAE9OAPgAUw3ACs68gJR1rN5MC2KAZGmp5C2sgooCDB0KDEwYwAHCGEYZBcAOl1MZABeDOQAIkZmEBYsjm4SAHoS5BBhAHdkBHEIBABrZCrgMHFkADFhYR5QSFhEFG7hAIpKOCg6XNYOcdw4Wgr0AFtcaDmKFIMGJlmuHj4BIVFkGB7O-gQLN0gVuhHkBzGKYHiLAEJJaWoLNogVg5nsFQuEOIFyAhRIxdlNYax0rcAclqEUeGVavUmi02h16MIViFxAiIPh6BASG9kBZvjJMBYiJwgS9IdDhIREvhhCwLFkqlBRAUHEUlGTiBDamyOVyeVlhI04MYssKuEA)

Answer (score 4):

The point of a guard is to allow you to narrow down when you're not sure what the type is:

What might work in your case is:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
    buzz?: string;
}


function hasBuzz(item: Foo|Required<Foo>): item is Required<Foo> {
    return typeof item.buzz === 'string'
}

const f : Foo = {
    bar: 'a',
    baz: 1,
    buzz: 'x'
};


const str : string = f.buzz; // error

if (hasBuzz(f)) {
    const str2 : string = f.buzz; // works
}
```

`Required` is a helper type that given another type will return that type with all properties required (available since ts 2.8). This will narrow down your `item` variable as being of type `Required<Foo>`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function hasBuzz(item: Foo): item is Foo & Required<Pick<Foo, 'buzz'>> {
    return !!item.buzz
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution that will work for any type and any field.

```js
type RequiredField<T, Key extends keyof T> = Omit<T, Key> & Required<Pick<T, Key>>;

function isFieldsDefined<T extends {}, U extends [keyof T, ...Array<keyof T>]>(
    obj: T, 
    keys: U
): obj is RequiredField<T, U[number]> {
    return keys.every((key) => key in obj);
}
```

`isFieldsDefined` takes 2 parameters:

1. the object of type `T`
2. a non empty array (one or more items) of properties that exists on interface `T`. `keyof` is T translates to `bar | baz | buzz`. This is great because if you tried to check for a field which doesn't exist on the interface (`booz` for instance), compilation will fail
3. for every key, we check that the key exists in the object

The type guard used by this function is an interesting one. But before I explain it, there's a few things to know.

`Omit` is a utility that creates a new type without the specified properties. Example:

```js
Omit<Foo, "bar"> === interface {baz: number, buzz?: string;}
```

`Pick` is a utility that creates a new type with the specified properties only. Example:

```js
Pick<Foo, "bar"> === interface {bar: string;}
```

`Required` is a utility that creates a new type where all the properties are required. Example:

```js
Required<Foo> === interface {bar: string; baz: number; buzz: string;}
```

Hence, `RequiredField` creates a new type where the specified fields are first omitted, then added back as non-undefineable. Below is how `RequiredField<Foo, "buzz>` transitions into the new type:

```js
1. RequiredField<Foo, "buzz">
2. Omit<Foo, "buzz"> & Required<Pick<Foo, "buzz">>
3. {bar: string; baz: number;} & Required<{buzz?: string}>
4. {bar: string; baz: number;} & {buzz: string}
5. {bar: string; baz: number; buzz: string}
```

Now that we know how `RequiredField` works, we may have a second look at `isFieldsDefined` type guard `obj is RequiredField<T, U[number]>`.

Since type `U` is an array of properties of `T`, `U[number]` will be a union type where each member corresponds with a value at an index in the array. Example:

```js
type Fields = ["bar", "baz", "buzz"];
Fields[number] === "bar" | "baz" | "buzz"
```

Therefore, here's a break down of the type guard for `isFieldsDefined(item, ["buzz"])`:

```js
obj is RequiredField<Foo, ["buzz"][number]>
obj is RequiredField<Foo, "buzz">
obj is {bar: string; baz: number; buzz: string;}
```

You may check that multiple fields are defined too: `isFieldsDefined(item, ["buzz", "bar"]);`

Answer (score -1):

You can use [definite assignment assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) when you reference the property.

```ts
function hasBuzz(item: Foo): string {
    return item.buzz!;
}
```

If you want to treat the object as definitely having `buzz` further on in the code, you can narrow the type:

```ts
interface DefinitelyBuzzed extends Foo {
    buzz: string;
}
```