# Generic typeguard for checking property existance

Tags: typescript, typeguards

The answer to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215092/typescript-key-property-type-guard) shows how to create a type to check that a property exists on an object.

I use the following variant :

```
const hasMetadata = <T extends object>(obj: T): obj is T & {metadata: unknown} => (
    Object.hasOwn(obj, 'metadata')
)
```

However I end up needing several such typeguards : I have a file with 20 or so. I am starting to consider simple code generation.

Before that, I wanted to make sure that a generic property check type guard is not possible in typescript.

It would look like that

```
const hasProp = <T extends object>(obj: T, key: string): obj is T & {[key]: unknown} => (
    Object.hasOwn(obj, key)
)
```

This code fails to typecheck with the following error

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type
```

Does someone knows of a way to achieve such a generic typeguard ?

Answer (score 1):

Just type your `key` with `string` !

```
const hasProp = <T extends object>(obj: T, key: string): obj is T & {[key: string]: unknown} => (
    Object.hasOwn(obj, key)
)
```

Comment: At first I though "If it compiles I don't understand why" then it compiled and I was amazed. However I realized it doesn't do what I want. The type `{[key: string]: unknown}` means that the object is indexable by *any* string. I want to specify that the object has a specific property with name `key`

Answer (score 0):

A generic `key` argument and a mapped return type is what I was looking for :

```
const hasProp = <T extends object, K extends string>(obj: T, key: K): obj is T & {[P in K]: unknown} => (
    Object.hasOwn(obj, key)
)
```